# How to pass rgb value coming in soap xml converting it into xsl and pass the rgb value

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In my soap response XML I am getting "options" parent node repeatedly.
Inside Parent node I have node"rgb" that contains some value. i am creating html with that data.
From Parent I am using description and when that description i m putting in the td I need to have the td color as rgb value in the option node present

### Sample XML

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ToggleOptionResponse xmlns="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com">
         <status>None</status>
         <originatingChromeOptionCode>SM</originatingChromeOptionCode>
         <originatingOptionAnAddition>true</originatingOptionAnAddition>
         <requiresToggleToResolve>false</requiresToggleToResolve>
         <configuration>

<options>

               <headerName>PRIMARY PAINT</headerName>
               <consumerFriendlyHeaderId>10</consumerFriendlyHeaderId>
               <consumerFriendlyHeaderName>Exterior</consumerFriendlyHeaderName>
               <optionKindId>68</optionKindId>
               <descriptions>
                  <description>Shadow Black</description>
                  <type>PrimaryName</type>
               </descriptions>
               <uniqueTypeFilter>N</uniqueTypeFilter>
               <rgbValue>0A0A0C</rgbValue>

            </options>

<options>

               <headerName>PRIMARY PAINT</headerName>
               <consumerFriendlyHeaderId>10</consumerFriendlyHeaderId>
               <consumerFriendlyHeaderName>Exterior</consumerFriendlyHeaderName>
               <optionKindId>68</optionKindId>
               <descriptions>
                  <description>Ruby Red Metallic Tinted Clearcoat</description>
                  <type>PrimaryName</type>
               </descriptions>
               <rgbValue>570512</rgbValue>

            </options>

       </configuration>
      </ToggleOptionResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

### Corresponding XSL

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com" version="1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="p">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">

    <xsl:for-each select="//p:ToggleOptionResponse/p:configuration/p:options">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <xsl:for-each select="p:headerName[not(.=preceding::*)]">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="." /></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>    
<tr>

      <td><xsl:value-of select="p:consumerFriendlyHeaderName"/></td>

<xsl:if test="p:headerName != 'PRIMARY PAINT'">
 <td><xsl:for-each select="p:descriptions/p:description">
         <xsl:if test="position() > 1 ">, </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:for-each></td>

    </xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="p:headerName = 'PRIMARY PAINT'">
 <td bgcolor ='#<xsl:value-of select="p:rgbValue">'>
<xsl:for-each select="p:descriptions/p:description">
         <xsl:if test="position() > 1 ">, </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:for-each></td>

    </xsl:if>

   </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>


    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying xslt first time, need inputs

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) here....

Instead of doing this...

```
 <td bgcolor ='#<xsl:value-of select="p:rgbValue">'>
```

Do this....

```
 <td bgcolor ='#{p:rgbValue}'>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, whose result will then be placed in the attribute.